# Temperatura da água

Tags: react

Estou querendo fazer um teste em React.

Quero colocar um valor no input e vai dizer se a água ferveu ou não, mas não tem botão.

Está tendo um erro e não sei como resolver.

```
class Temperatura extends Component {
            state = {query: '',};

           ferver = (query) =>{
                this.setState(() => ({
                 query:query.water =(query)=>{ return (query >=100) ? 'Agua ferveu.': 'Agua não ferveu.'}
                }))
            }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='App'>
              <form>
                <input
                    placeholder='Digite a temperatura da agua'
                    type='text'
                    value={this.state.query}
                    onChange={(e) => this.ferver(e.target.value)}
                />
                </form>
                <p>{this.state.query}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Temperatura;
```

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta com o erro que está tendo?

Answer (score 1):

`query` está sendo utilizado tanto como valor do seu input, mensagem de estado da água, e você também está tentando acessar uma propriedade chamada `water` nessa `query`, que não faz nenhum sentido.

Você não deveria estar inicializando o atributo `value` do seu input, pois isso irá "travar" o input com o valor passado para ele. Se você quiser um valor inicial nesse input, utilize o atributo `defaultValue`

Além disso a sintaxe utilizado no seu setState também não é válida. Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
class Temperatura extends Component {
    state = { mensagem: '' }

    ferver = (temperatura) => {
        this.setState({ mensagem: temperatura >= 100 ? 'Agua ferveu.' : 'Agua não ferveu.' })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <form>
                    <input
                        placeholder='Digite a temperatura da agua'
                        type='number'
                        onChange={(e) => this.ferver(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </form>
                <p>{this.state.mensagem}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```